# Editing users in ASP.NET from a grid

Tags: asp.net

I want to edit users who are from a grid view. Once I select the user (clicking on a row in a grid), I want to populate the selected user details into an edit pane(form with user fields) above the grid. Is this possible in asp.net.

Comment: how can it be made possible? I know how to dynamically populate the gridview. But I dont how I can make each row clickable and populate the edit pane. please assist...

Comment: Have you even had a go? What have you tried?

Comment: You should give a try and come up with the area that you a struggling with. Also providing more details can help you like what programming language you using. Anyway, i think this is what exactly you looking for : **http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/krishnasarala/edit-gridview-row-with-model-popup-extender-in-Asp-Net-ajax/**

Comment: I added a gridview (aspxGridView) and I used the ClientSideEvents-RowClick event. I thought this could trigger a click event on a row but nothing happens. I must admit I am new to ASP.NET.

Comment: I am using c# to implement this

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

Check this:

[GridView-DetailsView (Master/Detail)  Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16779/GridView-DetailsView-Master-Detail-Control)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Sure that is possible, you should use
 `gridview_SelectedIndexChanged` event to get the last selected row, thereby you can access the last selected row using SelectedRow property of your datagridview so you can populate your form controls with the  `datagridview.SelectedRow.Cells[index].Text`

In order to make each row clickable go in design view on your aspx page and click the datagridview right top corner arrow and click **Edit Columns**, from Available fields click on + sign on CommandField and chose Select, then click add and you got select link on every datagridview row.

Hope this help.